# Trying to convert the number numeric value in this string to a percent. Is there any easy way to do this in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Trying to convert the number numeric value in this string to a percent.  Is there any easy way to do this in powershell?

"Percentage of records ","0.02"

So, the output would look like :
Percentage of records , 2%

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert the string to a float data type (single, double, decimal), and then convert it back using a format string, like so:

```
"Percentage of records ", ([double]'0.02').ToString('P0')
```

And if you want it to output in a single line, you could use:

```
"Percentage of records: $(([double]'0.02').ToString('P0'))"
```

---

Explanation:

1. Convert your string to a float datatype: `[double]'0.02'`
2. Convert that float back into a string: `.ToString()`
3. But we want to format it as a percentage, so we supply `P0` as a parameter.

   i. `P` - means to format the value as a percentage, this performs the `N * 100` operation for you and then adds on the percent sign

   ii. `0` - controls the number of decimal places to show. In your case, you want to show zero decimal places.

Note: The percentage format string will round your value to the nearest decimal that you specify.

Example:

```
0.021.ToString('P0')
# returns 2%

0.025.ToString('P0')
# returns 3%
```

---

As @mklement0 pointed out in the comments. I hadn't considered that your sample may be a single string, like:

`'"Percentage of records ","0.02"'`

I assumed it was two strings, which you separated with a comma.

In the event it is a single string, then you need to extract the number to use it. Once you have isolated the number, then you can use my advice above:

```
$yourString = '"Percentage of records ","0.02"'

# probably the more "proper" way
$pctValue = ($yourString -split ',' -replace '"')[1]

# or

# a hacky way I just thought of that happens to work in this scenario
$pctValue = (iex $yourString)[1]
```

Explanation of first example:

- `-split ','` - Take the string, and break it out into multiple strings, separating them by comma
- `-replace '"',''` - Replace all instances of `"` with blank. The second parameter is optional since you are removing. Could be written as `-replace '"'`
- `(...)[1]` - This is saying to take the SECOND string that it returned (starts at zero). In this case it would be your `0.02` value.

Explanation of second example (this is a bit of a hack, but thought it would be fun to include anyway):

- `iex` - alias for `Invoke-Expression` - it's telling powershell to run whatever is inside of the string verbatim. So it's the equivalent of typing `"Percentage of records ","0.02"` into powershell and hitting enter. Which in PowerShell terms, that is the equivalent of passing it a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks, @Chad. I also recommend adding the usual caveat: [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @mat nice. If it answered your question please be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: The question has been answered - thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use -f ([format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx)) in powerhsell for build your string :

```
"Percentage of records, {0:0%} " -f 0.02
```

or in percentage :

```
"Percentage of records, {0:P0} " -f 0.02
```